# Como mudar o formato de serialização JSON do DateTime do PHP?

Tags: php, json, datetime, data, serialização

No PHP, quando uso um `json_encode` num objeto que do tipo `DateTime`, ele apresenta o seguinte resultado:

```
$date = new DateTime();

echo json_encode(compact('date'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Saída:

```
{
    "date": {
        "date": "2018-08-09 16:46:19.241129",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

Teste no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/71rH4t)

Esse formato aí pra mim é completamente indesejável. Eu queria que ele viesse no formato [`DateTime::ISO8601`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601).

Existe alguma maneira de costumizar a serialização do `DateTime` do PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alterar em tempo de execução o retorno da própria classe `DateTime` acredito que não seja possível - até porque isso poderia gerar efeitos colaterais na aplicação.

Uma solução trivial seria estender a classe `DateTime` para uma classe sua onde você define o comportamento desejado. Neste caso, quando a função `json_encode` recebe um objeto que implementa a interface `JsonSerializable`, ele retornará o valor retornado do método `jsonSerialize` previsto na interface. Assim, seria possível fazer algo como:

```
class DateTimeISO8601 extends DateTime implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->format(static::ISO8601);
    }
}
```

E então:

```
$d = new DateTimeISO8601('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

echo json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
```

Gerando a saída no formato esperado: `"2018-08-09T14:22:43-0300"`.

Se não for possível definir outra classe - caso não tenha controle sobre as instâncias do objeto, a solução será utilizar o método `format` mesmo no lugar de `json_encode`.

```
echo $d->format(DateTime::ISO8601) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 4):

Fiz um esquema parecido com a resposta do Anderson. Porém ao invés de implementar o `JsonSerializable` na classe de data, eu faço para a coleção inteira.

Assim:

```
class CustomJsonSerialize implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $data_to_serialize = $this->data;

        array_walk_recursive($data_to_serialize, function (&$value) {

            if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
                $value = $value->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
            }
        });

        return $data_to_serialize;
    }
}


$data = [
    'nome'          => 'Wallace',
    'data_cadastro' => new DateTime,
    'idade'         => 28,
    'profissoes'   => [
        [
            'nome' => 'Programador',
            'data_inicio' => new DateTime('-5 years')
        ]
    ]
];



 echo json_encode(new CustomJsonSerialize($data));
```

A resposta é:

```
{
    "nome": "Wallace",
    "data_cadastro": "2018-08-09T14:56:38-0300",    
    "idade": 28,
    "profissoes": [
        {
            "nome": "Programador",
            "data_inicio": "2013-08-09T14:56:38-0300"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Qual é a importância disso?

É que, em determinados casos, você não poderia alterar a instância de `DateTime` para uma outra implementação de classe. Assim, criando uma classe que alterar a coleção, ao invés de alterar a instância de `DateTime` em si, é possível converter todos os valores da estrutura para o formato desejado.

No caso do PHP 7, poderia ser mais útil ainda fazendo uma classe anônima!

```
$serialized_data = json_encode(new class ($data) implements JsonSerializable {

    protected $data;

    protected function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $data_to_serialize = $this->data;

        array_walk_recursive($data_to_serialize, function (&$value) {

            if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
                $value = $value->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
            }
        });

        return $data_to_serialize;
    }
});
```

## Atualização: Imitando o Javascript!

Com o Javascript, é possível fazer uma implementação onde o `JSON.stringify` recebe um callback no segundo parâmetro (`replacer`) que permite percorrer cada item do objeto passado, podendo retornar um valor diferente de acordo com uma condição.

Pensando nisso, fiz algo [parecido para o PHP](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/8ad0e55571c3182cdee5090b97dc2d9e).

Código-fonte:

```
function json_encode_callback($data, callable $callback, $options = 0)
{
    $isIterable = static function ($data) {
        return is_array($data) || $data instanceof \stdClass || $data instanceof Iterator;
    };

    $recursiveCallbackApply = static function ($data, callable $callback) use(&$recursiveCallbackApply, $isIterable) {
        if (! $isIterable($data))
        {
            return $callback($data);
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if ($isIterable($value)) {
                $value = $recursiveCallbackApply($value, $callback);
                continue;
            }
            $value = $callback($value, $key);
        }
        return $data;
    };
    return json_encode($recursiveCallbackApply($data, $callback), $options);
}
```

A função acima basicamente percorre cada item de uma estrutura e verifica defirmina o que será serializado para json de acordo com o retorno do callback.

Assim:

```
$obj = new stdClass;

$obj->date = new DateTime;

$obj->name = "Wallace";

$result = json_encode_callback($obj, function ($value) {
    return $value instanceof \DateTime ? $value->format('c') : $value;
});

var_dump($result);
```

O resultado é:

```
 string(53) "{"date":"2018-08-09T17:41:27-03:00","name":"Wallace"}"
```