# Formatar array de datas

Tags: laravel

Tenho uma aplicação Laravel com o seguinte código:

```
private function todosRegistros($id, $colunas = ['data', 'nivel'])
{
    return Leitura::select($colunas)->where('estacao_id', $id);
}

public function _24horas($estacao_id)
{
    return $this->todosRegistros($estacao_id)
        ->where('data', '>', Carbon::now('America/Sao_Paulo')
            ->subDay())->get();
}
```

Ao executar o método _24horas recebo um `array` com o valor dos níveis e a data de cadastro correspondente.

Acontece que a data retornada vem no formato americano `(YYYY-mm-dd)` e gostaria que viesse no formato brasileiro `(dd/mm/YYYY)`. Usando `Carbon::parse` consigo modificar data a data no `array` mas gostaria de uma alternativa onde modifico todas de uma vez. Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou desta forma https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators ?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Já sim. Mutators modificam o formato como a aplicação insere a informação no banco, eu gostaria apenas de mudar como ela é exibida não como ela está gravada. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Acho que você pode achar a solução para seu problema aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321242/como-mudar-o-formato-de-serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-json-do-datetime-do-php/321270#321270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira mais simples, faria um `appends` e um método para esse campo destinado a pegar a data e passar para formato `d/m/Y H:i:s` (ou `d/m/Y`), ***exemplo***:

***Model***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Leitura extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name']; 

    protected $appends = ['created_at_br'];

    public function getCreatedAtBrAttribute()
    {
        $value = date_create($this->attributes['created_at']);
        if ($value)
        {
            return $value->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');           
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

ou seja, nesse exemplo no `array` de `appends` foi inserido o nome `created_at_br` e foi também criado um acessor com o nome `getCreatedAtBrAttribute` sendo que o `get` significa resgatar o valor e o nome do `appends` com as iniciais em maiusculos e por fim `Attribute` no final, que é o padrão para métodos acessor.

Após fazer a pesquisa observe o exemplo:

```
>>> App\Models\Leitura::find(1)->toArray()
=> [
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "Stackoverflow",
     "created_at" => "2018-10-17 20:25:32",
     "updated_at" => "2018-10-17 20:25:32",
     "created_at_br" => "17/10/2018 20:48:18",
   ]
```

Nesse exemplo os dados obtidos não interferem naqueles que fazem relação com a base de dados, não atrapalham os formatos que é utilizado por exemplo em um `CRUD`.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Eloquent: Serialization - Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)</sub>

---

No seu caso poderia ser:

```
protected $appends = ['data_br'];

public function getDataBrAttribute()
{
    $value = date_create($this->attribue['data']);
    if ($value)
    {
        return $value->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');           
    }
    return null;
}
```

Se o seu banco for `MySQL` uma outra solução é na `SQL`:

```
Leitura::select(\DB::raw("date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y'),`nivel`"))
       ->where('estacao_id', $id)
       ->get();
```

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta, não sabia que era possível usar appends muito menos que podia formatar pelo SQL. Foi de grande ajuda.